# Different case conditions on different rows in same select SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, case-when

I want to do the following

```
Sel column1, 
           (CASE WHEN column1=x then 1
           ELSE
           2
           end) AS Key1,
           (CASE WHEN column2 =y then 1
           CASE WHEN column2 = z then 2 
           ELSE 
           3
           END) AS Key2
FROM table x
```

but it gives me  Syntax error, expected something like an 'END' keyword between an integer and the 'CASE' keyword. , any clues on how this can be done? How can I use multiple case whens on the same select? I do not want to use subqueries and inner joins.

thanks

Comment: Refer to SQL syntax on case statements. The problem is with the second case statement.https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I simply messed up the syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You got and extra `case` written in your statement.

Error at this row

```
CASE WHEN column2 = z then 2
```

Correct Query

```
  Sel column1, 
               (CASE WHEN column1=x then 1
               ELSE
               2
               end) AS Key1,
               CASE WHEN column2 =y then 1
               WHEN column2 = z then 2 
               ELSE 
               3
               END) AS Key2
    FROM table x
```

Comment: Thanks, I simply messed up the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

When using multiple `WHEN` conditions inside a `CASE` expression, the syntax is:

```
CASE
    WHEN <condition> THEN <result>
    WHEN <condition> THEN <result>
    ELSE
END
```

In your case, you have to remove the second `CASE` keyword in the second `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    (CASE
        WHEN column1 = x THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END) AS Key1,
    (CASE
        WHEN column2 = y THEN 1
        WHEN column2 = z THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END) AS Key2
FROM tableX
```

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by XING, the issue is an extra CASE in your original query.

You could use also another CASE syntax that it's a bit less redundant (you don't need to repeat the name of the column over and over again).

```
SELECT column1, 

     CASE column1 
       WHEN x THEN 1
       ELSE 2
     END AS Key1,

     CASE column2  
       WHEN y then 1
       WHEN z then 2 
       ELSE 3
      END AS Key2

FROM table x
```